# Custom authentication for IIS hosted WCF services?

Tags: wcf, iis-6, http-authentication

I have a WCF (v3.5 with webHttpBinding) service hosted in IIS 6. I would like to implement custom authentication before someone can access the service i.e. user details are stored in db.

But as I read on various posts and forums, for WCF services hosted in IIS only windows authentication is possible. There is no out-of-the-box way to deal with this.

Can someone suggest some work around? I believe this is a very common problem that many people must have come across before.

Comment: That's not true - IIS hosted services in IIS 6 support only **http** as the transport protocol - but they **most definitely** support custom authentication, certificate authentication and more

Comment: See the [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Questions%20and%20Answers&referringTitle=Home) - the question&answer section has a number of questions (and answers!) on how to use various authentication methods

Comment: @marc_s - The resource you pointed out is useful indeed, thanks. However, isn't the custom authentication supported only with wsHttpBinding and not webHttpBinding (since I am trying to build a RESTful service)?

Comment: Btw, I am new to WCF. So please bear with me if my findings are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could implement custom authentication with the help of following links -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/BasicAuthWCFRest.aspx
(Solution uses WCF REST starter kit)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/AutomaticCultureFlow.aspx
(Pointers without the starter kit)

I could do it without the starter kit by using Message Inspector on server side. I implemented the AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply methods to perform the authentication. I had to add the custom behavior to webHttpBinding since I am creating a RESTful service.

Comment: Another link that was useful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/29/creating-a-wcf-idispatchmessageinspector.aspx
(Has finer details and sample code)