# Adobe Drive CMIS connector and Authentication

Tags: adobe, http-authentication, cmis, adobe-drive

We have undertaken a project to make our DAM CMIS compliant and thus get connected with Adobe Drive using it's inbuilt CMIS connector. We will be following RESTful AtomPub binding of CMIS for this.

CMIS spec doesn't talk a lot about the authentication and seems like it is outside the scope of CMIS. I wanted to know how Adobe Drive client gets authenticated with any CMS/DAM using its CMIS connector. What is the mode of authentication used - is it HTTP basic, digest authentication or something custom. So I am not sure what would Adobe Drive send to get authenticated and what would it expect in the response. How do we pass back the session token that we will create.

Any pointers wrt this are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http basic

Take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/adobedrive/CMIS_Connector_Tech_Note.pdf

Pages 6-7 show what you'd get in a valid connection response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I had posted this a few months ago and have made lot of progress since then. Probably I should have posted back an answer to this. It's HTTP basic auth that I had to use with the help of some WCF classes. I created another thread as below which talks about the implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143221/custom-authentication-for-iis-hosted-wcf-services/5256688#5256688